# How to move instance to another region without losing any configuration?

Tags: amazon-ec2

i would like to move my AWS instance to another region.

Now, i will make it through the AMI.

But my question is if i move it to different region will it affect any configuration, or configuration will stay as it is?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an AMI from current region and copy the AMI to new region and then launch it. All your EC2 OS configurations will remain intact. However you need to make sure your new VPC/Security Group/DNS configurations match the corresponding entities in the old region.

1) Make sure your new VPC has same configuration as old one

2) Make sure your new subnet  has same configuration as old one

3) Make sure your new route table has same configuration as old one

4) Make sure your new NACL has same configuration as old one

5) Make sure your new security group has same configuration as old one

6) If you are accessing the instance using domain names,  make sure the Route 53 dns zone now points to the new Instance

Comment: Thanks for the answer